# Xcode Instruments: how to keep track of view controller's properties

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsarray, instruments

I'd like to see the allocations for the properties of a certain custom `UIViewController` object I have. In particular, I'd want to see what is happening with some `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` objects this view controller has as `(strong, nonatomic)` properties. I run the application by using the `Leaks` template of Instruments, and I see that the view controller object is allocated and deallocated whenever I push or pop it onto the navigation stack, but each time I navigate back and the view controller is popped, I see in Instrument's allocation summary that the `Live Bytes` are incremented always 400 KB aprox, it does not "return" to the value it had before navigating forth as I expected. I don't know what is causing this, and the leaks graph does not show any peak. I'm able to see the view controller object in the `Allocation Summary` list, since it is a custom class whose name I know, but the rest of the objects in list have names such as `__NSArrayM` that I don't know which arrays it is talking about.

How could I do a further search on this in Instruments? The view controller that is causing an increment in `Live Bytes` when navigating back and forth has a map view, could the tiles for the map be causing that?

Thanks in advance